# Declaring global variable <vector> issue

Tags: c++

This below is a snippet of my code

```
int lengthoftable;
vector<int> hashtable(lengthoftable);

int main(void) {
    cin >> lengthoftable;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to declare a global variable vector, initialized based on a variable size to be taken in the main body.

Question : Will it work since cin >> is below the declaration of the hashtable? Is there a way to solve this if it don't work? I want a global variable initialized on a variable to be taken in.

Comment: I think you should invest the time to resolve this issue by finding a way to do it without global variables.

Comment: Haha. No thanks :P I don't see the point, when I can get the assignment done in a shorter time. I will however, keep that in mind when I code professionally in the future.

Comment: @kingboonz: Do not worry much about the size of vector. They are known as dynamic vector and they maintain the size smartly/efficiently and of course correctly. You have taken the right step and .i.e. using the std::vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<int> hashtable;

int main(void) {
  int lengthoftable;
  cin >> lengthoftable;
  hashtable.resize(lengthoftable);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `resize()` initialize the elements *unnecessarily*? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/ says "If n is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of val, otherwise, they are value-initialized."

Comment: It's clear the OP has only a minimal understanding of the topic, it would be nice if you could provide some details about your solution.

Comment: @Arun I didn't get the impression the OP wanted to reserve capacity. I assumed that he wanted the elements initialized just as they would have been in his attempted use of the sized ctor.

Answer (score 3):

Why do really want to do the following?

```
vector<int> hashtable(lengthoftable);
```

How about doing it slighly differently as

```
vector<int> hashtable;

int main() {
    cin >> lengthoftable;
    hashtable.reserve( lengthoftable );
}
```

As a matter of fact, tracking the length of the vector and that too by getting the input from user, is a bad idea. A vector is meant to be a variable size array where the memory is managed internally with dynamic adjustment of size and capacity, there is no reason to track its length externally. It could even lead to inconsistency and error where the actual length and `lengthoftable` differs.